# Point cloud classification cgal

Tags: python, cloud, classification, point, cgal

Despite multiple attempts, the cgal point classification code fails to run on anything other than the demo dataset. I have attempted with multiple .ply files with a scalar field containing training labels.

The point datasets are around 2 million (which is relatively modest), I have attached a link to one of them https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DRvn75_3F_AQNrkSf2fBDUeZr8wld7Qk/view?usp=sharing.

The seg-fault occurs using both C++ & python. Given the video demo on the cgal website shows a larger cloud processed this seems strange.

Any cgal developers know why this may be?

Comment: Did you also try the C++ version? it might be an issue with the python bindings.

Comment: Yeah I did wonder this - that's my next port of call....

Comment: I have tried it using the C++ api and the same seg fault occurs. It'd be really useful to know why this was occurring - anyone?

Comment: You should fill an issue [here](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/issues). The developer that is taking care of this package is off this week.

Comment: Thanks sloriot - I will open an issue.

Comment: The issue is [here](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/issues/4816).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to cgal team this has been resolved. The issue was with the numbering of my labels scalar field (for the the training of the algorithm) of the ply file which was not contiguous.

To clarify, the field properties of the ply file should be as follows for use with the classification functions...

x double
y double
z double
red uchar
green uchar
blue uchar
nx double
ny double
nz double
label int

...with the last field "label" contents (i.e. the class labels) be something like -1 0 1 2.